# Vertically truncate text containing <br/>

Tags: html, css

I have this :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
            <br/>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
            <br/>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
            <br/>consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
            <br/>cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
            <br/>non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I set the row height? I would like the extra lines to be vertically truncated. I've already try :

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

and it works fine horizontally but not vertically. Do you have any tricks? Sometimes css feels like doing voodoo.

Comment: Unfortunately, only Opera supports this:  http://dev.opera.com/static/dstorey/text/text-overflow.html

Comment: Is the content allowed to expand the cell horizontally, but you want it to truncate the content after a certain number of br tags?

Comment: A few other questions, a) do you need to start with the opening <br/> tag, all that is doing is pushing the first sentence down, b) are you limited with what you can put in the HTML, is this layout pre-determined? c) at what point do you want to truncate? after X amount of <br/> tags? after a certain height?

Comment: @Andrew : no, the cell width is settled and with the given css lines are truncated horizontaly and show 3 dots ("..."). And technically yes, I want to truncate after a certain number of <tr/>, that is maybe a direction to explore.

Comment: a) not at all
b) layout pre-determined? I don't know what that means but I know that I may have very long texts into those cells.
c) Maybe the amount of lines (<br/> tags) is the best criterion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe table cells and rows grow to the height of the content that is inside of them.  I don't think it would be possible without wrapping the content in your  in a div, and then applying styling to limit the size of that div....

Also, it appears as if the line breaks (
) mess up the word wrapping...

Here is an example: [jsFiddle showing text-overflow in td](http://jsfiddle.net/h3EnR/)

Here is the code I used:
(html)

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="container-td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

(CSS)

```
.container-td {
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
width: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;}
```